# Sync WaitGroup not waiting for goroutine to assign pointer

Tags: go

Say I have the following code ([playground](https://play.golang.com/p/L8yWdVidyY-)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func createStr() *string {
    tmp := "foo"
    return &tmp
}

func main() {
    var (
        s  *string
        wg sync.WaitGroup
    )

    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()

        s = createStr()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("s after: %v", s)
}
```

I would have expected s to not equal nil.

However, if I add a small wait, I get s != nil ([playground](https://play.golang.com/p/pdQKehQxaLl)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func createStr() *string {
    tmp := "foo"
    return &tmp
}

func main() {
    var (
        s  *string
        wg sync.WaitGroup
    )

    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()

        s = createStr()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    fmt.Printf("s after: %v", s)
}
```

This just caused a bug in a program I wrote. What is happening with `sync.WaitGroup` that's not causing my program to wait for s to be assigned a string pointer in my go func?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your placement of `Add` method for `sync.WaitGroup` is wrong. Do not use `Add` inside a goroutine (anonymous goroutine here) but use it in the goroutine (main goroutine here) that's going to wait for it.

A probable situation that was happening in your code was that `wg.Wait()` didn't wait as the goroutine's `wg.Add(1)` wasn't called yet and hence `s == nil`. The following code fixes the issue:

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/X42dLQ9YYBO)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func createStr() *string {
    tmp := "foo"
    return &tmp
}

func main() {
    var (
        s  *string
        wg sync.WaitGroup
    )
    // Use wg.Add() here
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        s = createStr()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("s after: %v", *s)
}
```

Comment: ack! OMG, I need my coffee. Thanks! :) I can't accept your answer for another 9 minutes, thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped!